# Django 4. Invalid block tag on line 45: 'item.title', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?

Tags: django, django-templates

I work on Django 4
I am trying to create a view that will load a template view in django and I am getting the above error.

Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 4.0.2
Exception Type: TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:
Invalid block tag on line 45: 'item.title', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?
Exception Location: C:\Users\zinnurov.ramil\PycharmProjects\django_full_guide\venv\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py, line 552, in invalid_block_tag
Python Executable:  C:\Users\zinnurov.ramil\PycharmProjects\django_full_guide\venv\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.4

views.py

```html
def index(request):
    template_name = 'news/index.html'
    news = News.objects.order_by('-created_at')
    categories = Category.objects.all()
    context = {
        'title': 'Список новостей',
        'news': news,
        'categories': categories,
    }
    return render(request, template_name, context)
```

model.py

```html
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_index=True,
                             verbose_name='Категории')

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Категория'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Категории'
        ordering = ['-title']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="list-group">
                {% for cat in categories %}
                {% item.title %}
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Tdc5.png)
Have you got an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need `{{ item.title }}` instead of `{% item.title %}`. This is a syntax error

Btw it seems like `{{ item.title }}` will be None. Try `{{ cat.title }}` since you assigned "cat" in your for loop.

Comment: glad I helped @Ramil . Can you mark my answer as accepted?